# PAServer on Mac Mini M2 (Sonoma 14.2.1) with RadStudio 11.3/12 - Test connection button works but deployment not

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, rad-studio, paserver

I am working on a PC (Win11) with installed **RADstudio 11.3** (Problem also occurs with RADStudio 12). I am trying to deploy an app to a **Mac Mini (M2 chip)** via **PAserver 13.3.12.7** (downloaded from embarcadero for RADstudio 11.3) via this link: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/de/Installieren_des_Platform_Assistant_auf_dem_Mac.

The Mac runs **Sonoma 14.2.1** (the whole mac is brand new) with **XCode 15.1** and also with the **command line tools installed** (via command line `xcode-select --install`).

When I click the "check PAServer connection" button in RADStudio, it states that everything is fine and the connection is working. I also do get all provisioning profiles I have on my Mac and the SDK which is iPhoneOS 17.2. (I have tried to distribute the app to an iPad (10th gen. - 2022)). I can also find the connected iPad in my device list inside of RADStudio beneath Target.

Now as soon as I try to distribute the actual app, I get the error Message

> [PAClient Error] Error: E0003 Connection to "DevelopmentMac.local" on Port 64211 failed.

> PAClient Error] Error: E0003 Please check if PAServer running and configured for the use of port 64211

*(I translated this on the fly, so the actual English error codes might be slighly different)*

Same behaviour is TRUE for Simulated devices (e.g. iPhone 15 Pro(iOS 17.2)).

When I have a look onto my Mac while I try to distribute an app I can see a message being received by the PAServer:

> "/usr/bin/security" find-identity -v

I tried to install new certificates. I tried various certificate types. I tried various build configurations and provisioning profiles.

The docwiki from Embarcadero is not really helping me anymore, since I have worked through them twice by now. I am not sure if there is a chance to have a faulty certificate or profile which would result in this, but I am completely lost and I might also be missing something on the Embarcadero help.

Is it possible to get an OK on the "test connection" button but an error as if the server is not running on the actual connection?

Also, because I am super unsure by now what exactly I need:

1. Which certificate(s) do I need?
2. Is it still possible to use Wildcards or can I discard the Wildcard as an Identifier? (I have tried a specific Identifier as well as the Wildcard - result did not change)
3. How do I need to set up the *ad hoc* profile to deploy the app to the iPad?
4. I have read a few times about the Team profile, but I cannot find this anywhere (is this maybe the problem?) is this still up do date or is this team profile not necessary anymore? If this is still needed: where can I create/find this?

Comment: It's odd that you would have "connection failed", yet PAServer is obviously able to execute commands. It might be that the network connection is unreliable. As to the cert issues, you need at least an "Apple Development" cert, and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfBmJzPBhYs) shows how to get one, along with other requirements.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I wanted to participate on that livestream, but I could not make it due to an appointment! Thanks for sharing the link! This will for sure help me out so sort out the mess I produced on my way to finding an answer!

Comment: I have now also installed Delphi 12 and the corresponding PAserver. I have also watched the video suggested by Dave. Sadly I get the exact same error message with Delphi 12.

Comment: The best way to ensure you have proper certificates and everything else installed is to create new application in Xcode with the same ID as your Delphi application. Then deploy that application to the iPad. After that you can try again with the Delphi. I did that once with Tokyo when I had issues deploying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the solution to my problem, I will submit a short explanation and a longer one with the way to the solution down below.

**Short answer:** I have to use the IP-Address of the PAServer. The usage of the hostname "MyMac.local" is not working except for the "test connection".

**Long answer and way to the solution:**

After many other failed attempts to get this working on my computer, I took a second computer and tried to get things working. The computer I used was a Win10 computer with Delphi 11.2. I thought the problem would be the same, but (with the exact same options and configurations) it worked. This resulted in me thinking ok, this must be a firewall, a version or a Windows Problem.

To rule out any firewall problems, I deactivated everything. Still no change in the error behaviour! At this point I installed Wireshark and checked the commands sent to my network. I found the following:

> 120   6.126648    ---.---.---.--- ###.###.###.### DNS 154 Standard query response 0x76b8 No such name A MyMac.local SOA a.root-servers.net

*I deleted my IP-addresses and inserted - and # instead*

It seems like, for whatever reason the combination of this computer, my DNS Server and the mac are not happy together. As I inserted the fixed IP-Address everything worked like a charm in no time!